# Javascript simple function is not executing when write function to product-card-grid.liquid in shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-template

So I'm trying to call a simple alert message function inside my snippets/product-card-grid.liquid page.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong and why my function is not executing inside the product-card-grid page?

at the bottom of the page, I've added function called "foo()" which needs to execute the alert message when the page loads the single product page. As single product page contain this snippet.

However, it's not executing an alert message so how I can write the JS function here to make it work.

```js
{% comment %}
    Renders a product card using "Grid" style
    Accepts:
    - max_height: {Number} Maximum height of the product's image (required)
    - product: {Object} Product Liquid object (required)
    - show_vendor: {Boolean} Show the product's vendor depending on the section setting (optional)

    Usage:
    {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
{% endcomment %}
 <script>
   console.log('here....');
    </script>
<div class="grid-view-item{% unless product.available %} grid-view-item--sold-out{% endunless %} product-card">
  <a class="grid-view-item__link grid-view-item__image-container full-width-link" href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
    <span class="visually-hidden">{{ product.title }}</span>
  </a>

  {% capture img_id %}ProductCardImage-{{ section.id }}-{{ product.id }}{% endcapture %}
  {% capture wrapper_id %}ProductCardImageWrapper-{{ section.id }}-{{ product.id }}{% endcapture %}
  {%- assign preview_image = product.featured_media.preview_image -%}
  {%- assign img_url = preview_image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}

  {% unless preview_image == blank %}
    {% include 'image-style', image: preview_image, height: max_height, wrapper_id: wrapper_id, img_id: img_id %}
  {% endunless %}

  <div class="product-card__image-with-placeholder-wrapper" data-image-loading-animation>
    <div id="{{ wrapper_id }}" class="grid-view-item__image-wrapper product-card__image-wrapper js">
      <div style="padding-top:{% unless preview_image == blank %}{{ 1 | divided_by: preview_image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%{% else %}100%{% endunless %};">
        <img id="{{ img_id }}"
              class="grid-view-item__image lazyload"
              alt="{{ preview_image.alt }}"
              data-src="{{ img_url }}"
              data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
              data-aspectratio="{{ preview_image.aspect_ratio }}"
              data-sizes="auto"
              data-image>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <noscript>
    {% capture image_size %}{{ max_height }}x{{ max_height }}{% endcapture %}
    <img class="grid-view-item__image" src="{{ preview_image | img_url: image_size, scale: 2 }}" alt="{{ preview_image.alt }}" style="max-width: {{ max_height | times: preview_image.aspect_ratio }}px;">
  </noscript>

  <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title product-card__title" aria-hidden="true">{{ product.title }}</div>

  {% include 'product-price-listing', product: product, show_vendor: show_vendor %}
  <div>
<script>
  function foo() {
    alert('hellos');
  }
  foo();
    </script>
  <img src="logo.jpg" style="width:103px !important; padding-top: 3px;"><span style="font-size:13px; position:absolute; margin-top:17px;">From $ <script> calWeeklyFixedTerm({{ product.price | money_without_currency  }}, 12);</script>/week</span>
  </div>    
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see when viewing source if the script tag appears in the desired page?

Comment: Yes it display the script tag and function on the page but no effect of the function.

Comment: Can you open console in dev tools and see if the function `foo` exists?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right snippet?

Comment: Yes it shows me in the console too @Mike I'll place the photo soon on this post

Comment: Yes, @HymnZ that's the right snippet. I just copy and paste

Comment: @Jimil I am having exactly the same issue. Have you found a working solution?